# Disable default virtual host in apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, web-server

I've configured my name-based virtual hosts for Apache2 as follows:

1. copied /etc/var/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf to /etc/var/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf
2. edited ServerName, ServerAlias and DocumentRoot in mysite.com.conf
3. a2ensite mysite.com

Repeat step 1-3 for my nth site.

That works. But if I browse to the server's ip-address directly I get directed to 000-default. If I a2dissite that file, it takes the first of my custom config files and redirects to the according www-folder. I don't want that. I want that someone putting my server's IP address in the browser gets either an error message or nothing at all.
How can I achieve that?